# How does the trade id relate to the effect id?

Tags: trade, effects

After successfully creating an offer via the Horizon API, I use the transaction hash to get the effects. This may include trades. Later I retrieve all trades for my account. Now I want to match the trade effects with the respective trades. However, the ids are not exactly the same.

The ids have the form `123456789012-1` for trades or `00123456789012-0` for the effects. The long prefix is shared (ignoring leading zeros) but the suffix is different for the same trades. What do the parts of the ids stand for and how can I match them?

Answer (score 1):

Effect id consists of two parts: `{operation_id}-{effect_application_order}`.

Operation ID is an encoded unique identifier of the operation, which contains:

- Ledger sequence
- Transaction application order within ledger tx set
- Operation application order within tx

The second part is a particular effect order (each operation yields zero or more effects).

The difference is that `/effects` Horizon endpoint returns all effects including `set_options`, `change_trust`, `manage_data` etc, while `/trades` endpoints allows you to retrieve only `trade` effects. And trade id does not match effect id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. So you mean the second part, the effect order, should be identical, too? My problem is that they are not. However, it seems the effects are generated in symmetrical pairs. Maybe I'm picking the wrong ones.

Comment: Yes, when a trade occurs, you get two effects (one per each account participating in trade): selling `asset1` for `asset2` and selling `asset2` for `asset1`. Note the `account` field of Horizon response.

Comment: I can't confirm that the effect order matches the trade id. I just tried the last trades on the platform. Several ended with "-0" while the respective effects ended with "00...001" and "00..002" respectively. But I can't really figure out a pattern. For operations with many effects the trade order seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: Just checked, you are right, effects from the `/trade` endpoint have different ids if you compare them to entries from `/effects` endpoint. Also, the id order counter in trades starts from 0 while effects counter starts from 1. Sorry, my mistake.